# How to start XAMPP from a shortcut

Tags: gnome, shortcuts, xampp

I've had Xampp installed on my machine for a while but I have yet to figure out how to start the GUI from a shortcut.

At the moment I am launching

```
sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
```

From the terminal every time I want to start it, but it's pretty annoying to have to go through the terminal for this every single time.

I have already tried pasting that command in a shortcut and when I try to start it nothing happens. Here's how my shortcut looks:

[image]

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: Do you get a launcher icon after you start it? Also, any special reason for using camp vs the native lamp?

Comment: No launcher icon. I am more comfortable with xampp than the other options, also I tried installing lamp and it uninstalled gnome rendering my laptop unusable.

Comment: Maybe this solution would work - https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2324973

Comment: The gksu package has been removed from ubuntu so there's no way to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this link.

https://junise.wordpress.com/2017/07/23/xampp-in-ubuntu-desktop-shortcut-launcher-entry-home-folder-shortcut-inside-htdocs/

Change this sentence:

```
Exec=sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
```

And add:

```
Terminal=true
```

at the end of *.desktop* file.

Comment: I'm sure this didn't work a few months ago, but now it does! Thank you!

Comment: nothing, I had same problem.

Comment: nice solution, but is there a way so that once we have entered the password, the terminal window should close automatically

Comment: Whithout terminal=true works perfect,no unessesery opening terminal when we click on icon(Ubuntu 18.04) .

Answer (score -1):

I'm using lampp, but this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037792/ubuntu-18-04-xampp-desktop-icon-there-was-an-error-launching-the-application#1059669) worked for me in ubuntu 18.04. I think it should work for you too, good luck.

edit: You may need to modify some of the content in `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/xampp.policy` for example the line that reads 

`<annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run</annotate>`

you should change that to reflect your path instead like this

`/opt/xampp/manager-linux-x64.run`

I don't remember if xampp installs into /opt/lampp or not, but check that your path is correct.